# Which is more customizable between jQuery Mobile and Sencha Touch in terms of UI?

Tags: jquery-mobile, sencha-touch

I am an iOS developer with decent experience, After a lot of decsion making, we have coome to a conclusion of using phoneGap for our next project which is suppose to be a multi platform app.
Now the question is what to use with PhoneGap, Sencha and jQuery Mobile?

I visited old posts at SO,Quora and a lot of blogs and came to a conclusion that, jQuery Mobile is good to start and learn but Sencha is much more powerful in terms of controls,MVC on client and extensibility.

I have used  jquery,jquery plugins and ExtJS in the past and I am fine  with either of their mobile counterparts .

So coming to the point, Our application will be designed by a designer who will not know what we will be using to make the app.

he will give us wireframes of the application and slices for images to put on buttons,tab bars etc.

This is how our standard iOS design process works.
So which of the two frameworks will suit this kind of development style where I will be able to replicate the UI given by the designer.

Comment: If you know jQuery, then jquery-mobile seems like the sensible choice. I will point out however that I have been hugely disappointed with it, some of the fundamental features (fixed headers, page transitions) can be very buggy. Hopefully they will be fixed, but in it's current state thats a deal breaker for me. In short, I wish I'd used Sencha to build my app.

Answer (score 0):

Coming from iOS, Sencha Touch might be a little closer to what you're used to. Having had a little iOS experience, I feel like ST has a much closer layout system. jQuery Mobile would be best if the implementor is used to building things for the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I think both are equally customizable. Having that said ST provides more built in components and hooks whereas jqm wants you to do more on your own. Both frameworks differ extremely in their approach. Jqm uses a declarative designer friendly approach whereas ST uses an OOP programmer friendly approach.